# target_blank working for two javascript functions even though it is applied for one javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two javascript functions as shown below

```
    <body>
       <script language="javascript">
     function generate(){
                            var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                            var f = document.form;
                            f.target = "_blank";
                            f.method="post";
                            f.action='ViewPO.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                            f.submit();

                        }
    function generate1(){
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var f = document.form;
                        f.method="post";
                        f.action='purchaseAction.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                       // f.submit();
                    }
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="generate1()" />
                            <input type="submit" value="View PO" onclick="generate()"/>
```

I have given `f.target="_blank"` for one javascript function.when i click on "View PO" button it is opening in another tab of the browser which is very good.but when i close that tab and immediately click on "Save" it is also opening in another tab of the browser which i dont need it in the sense it should open the page in the same tab.So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because calling `generate` will set the `target` value of the `form` to `_blank`, this value is saved to the form's properties so when `generate1` is called it uses the same target value.

So just reset the value of `target` property in `generate1`

```
function generate1() {
  var table = document.getElementById('my_table');
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var f = document.form;
  f.method = "post";
  f.target = "";
  f.action = 'purchaseAction.jsp?rowCount=' + rowCount;
  // f.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `f.target = "_self";` in  your `generate1()` function as

```
   function generate1(){
                    var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                    var f = document.form;
                    f.method="post";
                    f.target = "_self";
                    f.action='purchaseAction.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                   // f.submit();
                }
```

[target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_target.asp) property that was set in the form by `generate()` was used by the form in `generate1()` method so you need to reset the same to default which is `_self`.